# new site on azure-mobile.net

Tags: azure, mobile, azure-mobile-services

Is it now possible to create new site on azure-mobile.net domain in Azure?
I cannot now create new Mobile Service in Azure Portal (classic), I received the error:

> Mobile Service is no longer accepting new subscriptions. Please use
>   Azure Mobile Apps instead.

But when I try to create Mobile App or App Service, I can create site only in .azurewebsites.net domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create new Mobile Service as the service is being deprecated.  Mobile App is part of App Service that include Web App, Mobile App, Logic App and API App and this service only uses the azurewebsites.net domain.

Comment: That's right, and you get even more functionality. See [Mobile Services vs. App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-value-prop-migration-from-mobile-services/).