# Visual Studio 2015 Deploys On Azure Mobile Services

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015

I created an Azure Mobile Service project using Visual Studio 2015 and to choose for it to be hosted on the cloud, however I found out that uses the domain .azure-mobile.net which is deprecated and new services can not be deployed on it.

My question is how could I now create a publishing profile on azure using VS 2015
to host on the azurewebsites.net domain

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [new site on azure-mobile.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919738/new-site-on-azure-mobile-net)

Answer (score 0):

Download the Azure SDK for .NET: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/ and you can see the normal domain extension azurewebsites.net. Then you can follow this way for publish: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk